# Win32 API used to get active directory tickets?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Does anyone know the Win32 API used to get active directory(kerberos) tickets?

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543735/kerberos-difference-btween-jaas-connection-to-server-and-sql-server-trusted-con) my understanding is that the SQL Server driver uses the Win32 API to get TGT tokens from the local OS instance.  (Providing trusted connections)

Does anyone know what this API is and the doco and examples for using it? (For C/C++/JNA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous to the change that is described in the "Summary" section of this article, programs could use the Win32 LsaCallAuthenticationPackage API specifying KERB_RETRIEVE_TICKET_REQUEST and either KerbRetrieveEncodedTicketMessage or KerbRetrieveTicketMessage message types to retrieve a Kerberos ticket-granting-ticket (TGT) and the associated session key.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308339

Comment: The link has broken meanwhile; here's an archived version: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/308339